# passing json data to chartjs

Tags: json, charts, chart.js

**JSON.js**

```
    var Jsondata = {
            "label1": 0,
            "label2": 0,
            "label3": 2,
            "label4": 0,
            "label5": 0
        }
var labels = //?? have to get the labels from the Jsondata
var data = //?? have to get the numbers from the Jsondata
```

and i am using this to make a line graph using chartjs and the code is as follows.

```
 type: 'line', 
          data: { 

              labels: labels  //["label1","label2","label3","label4", "label5""], 

 datasets: [{ 
              label:'',                   
              fill: 'false', 
              data: data  //[0, 3, 6, 4, 5,3,2],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built in `Object` helpers `keys()` and `values()`:

```
var Jsondata = {
            "label1": 0,
            "label2": 0,
            "label3": 2,
            "label4": 0,
            "label5": 0
    }
var labels = Object.keys(Jsondata)
var data = Object.values(Jsondata)
```

labels:
`["label1", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"]`

data:
`[0, 0, 2, 0, 0]`